Apache 2.4 reverse proxy provides stale content for Tomcat / Confluence backend
Environment:
Apache 2.4 reverse proxy on Windows server 2019 in front of Tomcat 8.9.x / Confluence.
(Please no advice to change Win, can't change this).
Proxy as such works fine.
Webpage delivery from Confluence is slow (DOM content delivery ~ 6s, total content 7-12s).
Desired improvement:
Use of reverse proxy with disk cache to improve user experience.
I used this Confluence config example (adapted to Win, of course). I do not use "Header unset Set-Cookie" or "RequestHeader unset Cookie" since this results in beeing redirected to the login page.
My intention is not only to cache the static content (path "/s" for Confluence), but as much as possible (i.e. root path "/", beside "/rest"), for caching only path "/s" still results in poor performance for most pages.
The current configuration generally fulfills this purpose (DOM ~ 1,5s).
Problem:
Disk cache temporarily provides stale content after pages were edited.
E.g.: draw.io object gets new text "test10". Saved. After a few seconds popup says "This page has been edited". A click results in fetching the older version with "test9" (same applies to F5). Only if I go to a different page and back again the latest content will be displayed.
Current config:
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
        
<Proxy *>
  Require all granted
</Proxy>
    
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8090/ 
ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8090/
    
CacheRoot "D:\Apache24\cache"
CacheQuickHandler OFF
CacheIgnoreCacheControl On

CacheDirLevels 2
CacheDirLength 1

<Location "/">
  CacheEnable disk
  Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public, must-revalidate"           
  CacheHeader on
  CacheDetailHeader on
</Location>

<Location "/rest">
  CacheDisable on
</Location> 

In the meantime I removed "CacheLock on" / "CacheLockPath" / "CacheLockMaxAge" to avoid any chance to produce stale content (even with the risk of multiple refresh runs towards the backend).

Confluence being that slow is not normal. You should try to solve the cause, not the symptoms.

Sorry, not helpful. (a) Look up "Confluence slow" - plenty of hits (b) I did not ask about Confluence, but Apache cache. Even IF Confluence performed good I'd still be in need of a cache which works as expected.
